# Joi - use 'valid' for specific condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I try to validate the query parameter userId.

If a user is an admin then he can use any user id.

If no - then use the only id from a specific array.

```
const validUserIds = isUserAdmin ? req.query.userId : userIds;
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    userId: Joi.string().optional().regex(UUIDRegex).valid(validUserIds),
  });
Joi.validate(req.query, schema).then(.....);
```

Problem: When we send bad user id (e.g. 'abc' etc, regex validation should fail) and the user is the admin then validation pass successfully.

Can I create something like this: if the user is the admin then validate only by rexeg if no - validate by regex + valid id list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Joi.when` sounds like the right function here.

```
userId: Joi.string()
  .regex(UUIDRegex)
  .when('isUserAdmin', {
    is: false,
    then: yourValidateUserIdFunction() // validate
  });
```

Reading through this, we check if the user ID is a string, then we check that it matches the `UUIDRegex` for all users, and finally we check if the user ID is valid when the user is not an admin.

Alternatively, if `isUserAdmin` is outside of the Joi schema, create two different schemas based on that information:

```
const isUserAdmin = true;
if (isAdmin) {
  joi.object({
    userId: Joi.string().regex(UUIDRegex),
  });
} else {
  joi.object({
    userId: Joi.string().regex(UUIDRegex).validateUserId(), // validate
  });
}
```

Comment: The problem is isUserAdmin, it's outside of Joi schema. I have req.query object to validate. And I have another variable req.user.isAdmin, so I can't write .when('req.user.isAdmin', { is: false ..... })

Comment: Thanks for that feedback. I've tried to respond by showing how you could fork the schema definition based on information outside the schema.

Comment: Thx for the idea. I decided to create 1 schema because I have a lot of keys. For user id I wrote this one: userId: ? isAdmin ? Joi.string....... : Joi.string......

Comment: @JakeWorth What if I want to check one of the schemas to validate against the array items and if it matches move to the next item? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74658952/joi-validations-if-object-matches-the-schema-validate-against-it-from-multiple